# Unhandled exception during ng lint in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I am trying to run `ng lint` on my angular project. I migrated an Angular project from TSLint to ESLint, but when I run `ng lint` I get this error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid lint configuration. Nothing to lint.
```

What could have gone wrong with the configuration?

**ng version**:  Angular CLI: 11.2.9, Angular: 11.2.0

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        //"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", TODO: check warnings
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
          "error",
          {
            "selector": "variable",
            "modifiers": ["const", "exported"],
            "types": ["function"],
            "format": ["camelCase"]
          },
          {
            "selector": "variable",
            "modifiers": ["const","exported"],
            "types": ["string", "number", "array", "boolean"],
            "format": ["UPPER_CASE"]
          }
        ],

        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "libs-common-angular": {
      "root": "projects",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "libs/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "libs/package.json"
          }
        ,
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
},
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "libs/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "libs/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "libs/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "libs/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "libs-common-angular"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "libs-common-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "pre-release": "npm --prefix libs version patch && ng build libs-common-angular",
    "release": "npm --prefix libs version patch && ng build libs-common-angular && npm publish --@owi dist/libs-common-angular"
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^11.2.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "2.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "2.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "2.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "2.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that a comment in your *.eslintrc.json*? Here: `//"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", TODO: check warnings`. That would make it invalid. Comments in JSON are not supported.

Comment: it's comment, but even after I deletet it, it still has the same error

Comment: I just had this same error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this same error doing the exact same thing.

I noticed I had this in the auto-generated .eslintrc.json file:

```
"ignorePatterns": [
  "projects/**/*"
],
```

If I'm reading that pattern right, it's saying to ignore everything in my projects, so it makes sense now that it couldn't find anything to lint. I removed this pattern and linting worked.

So it looked like this:

```
"ignorePatterns": [],
```

Comment: I love you! Saved me a lot of trouble troubleshooting after switching over to monorepo structure.